# WP8.1 get device total memory

Tags: windows-phone-8

In wp8, we have [devicetotalmemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.devicetotalmemory%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property. As MSDN says, it returns the physical RAM size of the device in bytes.

But when I tested it on my lumia 920 with 32Gb storage it returns 898Mb size.
My device is running wp8.1 developer preview. 
Can you tell me what wrong with total memory property? Maybe I do something wrong, or there is 
bug in wp8.1.

Comment: Are you targeting Runtime or Silverlight? And you want to find free spave on IsolatedStorage?

Comment: WP 8.0. Silverlight. I need to know whole device storage size.

Answer (score 0):

It returns device RAM size.looks like you have device with 1GB RAM.

**Remark:**
The value returned is less than the actual amount of device memory, but can be used to help determine memory consumption requirements.

Comment: Oops, my bad. There is any way to get device storage size?